# Double product price from XML imported file in Woocommerce

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I have a XML file that is uploaded to a script then into products from woocommerce, but I am having double prices as seen above, so the sale price is not visible.

```
<produkt>
    <forhandler>xxx.xx</forhandler>
    <kategorinavn>xxxx</kategorinavn>
    <produktnavn>Hugo Boss Navigator 1513531</produktnavn>
    <produktid>1533</produktid>
    <beskrivelse>Hugo Boss Navigator 1513531</beskrivelse>
    <nypris>122.00</nypris>
    <glpris>122.00</glpris>
    <fragtomk>29 DKK</fragtomk>
    <billedurl>some url</billedurl>
    <vareurl>some link</vareurl>
</produkt>
```

I would like if `<nypris>` equals `<glpris>` then delete `<glpris>` I have been trying to do it in a PHP script that I have importing from a xml file.

Is there any good way to do it?

I'am look for help because I have a poor knowledge.

Comment: Could you show us your script which read the XML file and import the data into your WooCommerce shop? Is that possible? 
Or do you want to edit the XML file **before** you upload it to the "import script"?

Comment: Think it would be easyer to edit the xml file before adding it to the import script

Comment: Ok ... you wrote that you tried to bulit an php script which change the xml data. Could you show us the code? Maybe we can help you to find the error.